# Which of the following groups $Q$ is normal in $G$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups, sylow-theory

Which of the following groups can be a normal $2$-Sylow subgroup of a non-abelian group $G$ of order $56$?

1) $\mathbb{Z}_8$

2) $\mathbb{Z_4}\times \mathbb{Z_2}$

3) $\mathbb{Z_2}\times \mathbb{Z_2}\times \mathbb{Z_2}$

I know that if a $2$-Sylow subgroup is the only such Sylow subgroup, then it will be normal in $G$, however, I am not sure how to apply it to this .

Thanks for any help.

[Editor's note: I rephrased the first sentence to match with my interpretation. IMHO it is the version that makes sense as a question, and the OP seems to like my answer, so I guess it is correct. Cheers, JL.]

Comment: It depends on $G$. Are you asking whether a Sylow $2$-subgroup of the given type is normal in some nonabelian group of order $56$, or in all nonabelian groups of order $56$?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Hint: Those candidate subgroups are all abelian. If a $2$-Sylow subgroup $P$ is normal, then conjugation by an element of order seven is an automorphism of $P$. Because the big group is non-abelian, that automorphism must be non-trivial, and thus of order seven. Which of those groups have automorphisms of order seven?

Comment: Just to ask why is conjugation by element of order 7 an Automorphism?

Comment: I know $Aut(Z_8)=u(8)$ (order 4), not sure about the other two.

Comment: Working under the assumption that $P\unlhd G$, $|G|=56$. If $x\in G$ is of order seven (exists by Cauchy), then the mapping $p\mapsto xpx^{-1}$ is 1) a bijection (you can invert it), 2) a homomorphism, 3) maps $P$ to itself (because of normality), 4) the identity mapping if and only if $x$ commutes with all of $P$.

Comment: You got $Aut(\Bbb{Z}_8)$ right. Good. To determine  $Aut(\Bbb{Z}_4\times\Bbb{Z}_2)$ you should first determine what choices are there for the image of $(1,0)$. Given that, then figure out how many choices remain for the image of the other generator $(0,1)$. The last candidate group is a 3-dimensional vector space over the field $\Bbb{Z}_2$, so its automorphisms can be thought of as invertible 3x3 matrices.

Comment: thanks a lot. Wouldn't an element of any other order work too? I.e. I don't quite get why we have to consider an element of order 7. Thanks!

Comment: You need to be sure that an element of the prescribed order exists in $G$. And $|G|=56=2^3\cdot7$.

Comment: I see... How about element of order 2,4 or 8, which exists by Sylow theorem?

Comment: Those are in some Sylow $2$-subgroup. And if a Sylow $2$-subgroup is normal, it is unique.

Comment: Oh. I forgot to add that once you find an automorphism $\phi$ of order seven of an abelian group $P$ of oreder eight, you can create a non-abelian group of order $56$ as a semidirect product $P\rtimes C_7$, where a generator of $C_7$ acts on $P$ via $\phi$.